# having error while compiling with static method

Tags: c++, static-methods

Stated on my title, trying to compile my file with a static method inside my code.
My `computeCivIndex()` is trying to get 5 inputs from user and do a calculation and return the float value back.

`this.sunType` is for java syntax, but for V++ what should I use to link them together if both are the same name?

I have getter and setter methods in my code and also 2 constructors which is too lengthy to be posted.

This is my error:

```
test.cpp:159: error: cannot declare member function ‘static float LocationData::computeCivIndex(std::string, int, int, float, float)’ to have static linkage
test.cpp: In static member function ‘static float LocationData::computeCivIndex(std::string, int, int, float, float)’:
test.cpp:161: error: ‘this’ is unavailable for static member functions
```

The code:

```
class LocationData
{   
    private:
    string sunType;
    int noOfEarthLikePlanets;
    int noOfEarthLikeMoons;
    float aveParticulateDensity;
    float avePlasmaDensity;
    public:
    static float computeCivIndex(string,int,int,float,float);
};
static float LocationData::computeCivIndex(string sunType, int noOfEarthLikePlanets,int     noOfEarthLikemoons, float aveParticulateDensity, float avePlasmaDensity)
{
    this.sunType = sunType;
    this.noOfEarthLikePlanets = noOfEarthLikePlanets;
    this.noOfEarthLikeMoons = noOfEarthLikeMoons;
    this.aveParticulateDensity = aveParticulateDensity;
    this.avePlasmaDensity = avePlasmaDensity;
    if(sunType == "Type O")
         //and more for computation
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`static` declaration defers from `static` implementation. Static implementation means that your function symbol is only available within the file where it is implemented.

Simply remove the static before the function implementation. Futhermore, static function are class function, you can't access non-static members of the class in them. Those are meant to be used without object instance, an so, there is no instance variables.

```
float LocationData::computeCivIndex(string sunType, int noOfEarthLikePlanets,int     noOfEarthLikemoons, float aveParticulateDensity, float avePlasmaDensity)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error seems reasonably clear to me:

> error: ‘this’ is unavailable for static member functions

Basically, because the member is `static`, it doesn't execute within the context of a particular instance of the type - so using `this` within the method is meaningless. You *do* try to use `this`, hence the error.

From the [MSDN documentation for `static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx):

> When you declare a member function in a class declaration, the static keyword specifies that the function is shared by all instances of the class. A static member function cannot access an instance member because the function does not have an implicit this pointer. To access an instance member, declare the function with a parameter that is an instance pointer or reference.

It sounds like you just don't want to declare the member as being static.

(As an aside, I don't like the description saying it's "shared by all instances of the class" - I prefer the idea that it's not specific to any particular instance of the class. There don't have to be *any* instances created, at all.)

Comment: its a requirement for my homework that it must be a static method , so is there a way to link them?

Comment: @HengAikHwee: Sounds like an odd requirement. Can you change the signature to take a reference to an instance? Could you return a new instance instead?

Comment: Hmm do you mean LocationData data; data.sunType = sunType; ?

Comment: @HengAikHwee: Well *something* like that - although it's pretty odd for a method called `compute...` to change the data within an object anyway. It's hard to help you without knowing what you're trying to accomplish. Why are you trying to use `this` at all?

Comment: im trying to do a computation base on the user 5 inputs from the cin. There will be another class which will trigger this computation

Comment: @HengAikHwee: You've got the inputs as parameters though... what instance of LocationData are you interested in?